Packaging and Distributing Mathematica Code
I am trying to distribute my Mathematica Code in the form of a package. It can be compiled to a single file, numerous functions. So, I created the following directory structure:
MGroups
│   MGroups.m
│   PacletInfo.m
│
└───Kernel
        init.m

where MGroups.m contains all of my functions. PacletInfo.m contains the following lines:
Paclet[
    Name -> "MGroups",
    Version -> "1.0",
    MathematicaVersion -> "12.3+",
    Description -> "Finite group theory in Mathematica.",
    Creator -> "Firstname Lastname <email>",
    Extensions -> {
        {"Kernel", Root -> "Kernel", Context -> "MGroups`"}
    }
]

and Kernal/init.m contains the single line Get["MGroups(backtick)MGroups"]`.
Now, when I try to run PacletBuild["D:/11/MGroups"], I get the warning PacletToolsGeneral::warning: Note: file 'MGroups\MGroups.m' was not included in built paclet.. I am not quite sure why this is happening. If I choose to ignore this warning and go on regardless, then I get errors in future while using the package. It does not recognise any of the functions... I would appreciate help. Also note that I would like to add documentation to my package, so I also need to know how that may be done.
Also, this is my first time packaging and distributing Mathematica code in this form. So, if I am confused and there is a better way to make Mathematica ``packages,'' then please let me know, and I will go that way.
Thankyou...

Move the MGroups.m file into the Kernel folder, then throw away the init.m file

@JasonB.—Thankyou for the suggestion, I have tried it and it works perfectly... I have a question: I see repositories on Github of Mathematica Packages. And usually they also have the same directory structure as I had originally. So this change that I have made right now, is it a standard way of doing things? Or is it not standard but works because of the setup I may be following...? Because then, I would like to make necessary changes to make things like they are intended to be. Thanks again...
